# VSCode doesn't recognize html files

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

After clearing system's cache, VSCode doesn't recognize html files. So, now I can see brackets icon only in `htm` files. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKE5j.png). And before clearing `html` files were also recognized. So, what's the matter and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

select the HTML Tag on the Bottom, it will open the modal and select the HTML in the opened modal.. it works

Comment: But you have to do this every time.

Answer (score 9):

I found an answer on another SO thread.

Open your `settings.json` file on VSCode and include this line `"files.associations": {"*.html": "html"}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner and had the same problem (no Closing-tags, no Brackets-icons, no auto-html:5 option, and no right-click-option to "Open with Live Server").

Solution: Answer from Chidimo + Configure file association for ".html" and select HTML.

Click on Language (see print screens Sathish) for 'Select Language Mode'
Then type: 'Configure file association for ".html' and select HTML. Restart VSC.

My 4 problems are solved with this solution!
(Thanks to *@Rick* ;-))